# Open Multiple PDF Files with External Program

Tags: file, pdf, vbscript

I am trying to create a script that opens all PDF files in a certain folder, and in a certain program at the same time. Below is what I currently have and it is not working for me.

```
Dim objFSO
Dim MyFile
Dim MyFolder
Dim objShell

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New folder")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe")

For Each MyFile In MyFolder.Files
    If Right(MyFile.Path,4) = ".pdf" Then
        objShell.Exec("PDFXCview" + MyFile.Path)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is `PDFXCview` an environment constant recognised by your system? Did you try to run the string you want to evaluate from the command prompt firstly?

Comment: I don't believe it is. Mainly I'm just trying to get all PDF's in that folder to open in that program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to just send all the file names on PDFXCview.exe's command line:

```
Dim objFSO, MyFile, MyFolder, objShell, strPDFFiles

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New Folder")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strPDFFiles = ""
For Each MyFile In MyFolder.Files
    If StrComp(Right(MyFile.Name, 4), ".pdf", VBTextCompare) = 0 Then
        strPDFFiles = strPDFFiles & " """ & MyFile.Name & """"
    End If
Next

objShell.CurrentDirectory = MyFolder
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("""C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe""" & strPDFFiles)
```

The command line could of course overflow with a large number of files. Chances are PDFXCview chokes on too many open files before that though. Either way, to reduce the command line's lenght the code above only collects the PDF files' names and not their full paths, and makes sure PDFXCview finds them by changing CurrentDirectory to their folder. If you don't like that, change back to .Path and there'll be no need for the CurrentDirectory change.

There's also a change to use StrComp in VBTextCompare mode for a case insensitive extension lookup in case any of the files are named .PDF or so. The added double-quotes are there to handle any spaces in file names. And they are doubled up since they are themselves within double-quotes.

Comment: When I try to run this it gives me an error that says the path is not found. I threw together what I had from researching on the internet so maybe I have to much going on. All I need to do is to open all pdf files in a certain folder in the PDFXCview program.

Comment: One easy way to avoid fat-fingering paths is to Shift-Right-Click the folder/file icon and choose "Copy as path", then paste it into the code.

Comment: The path does exist as far as I can see. The error that comes up is a Windows Script Host and states that the error is on Line: 4 Char: 1 Error: Path not found Code: 800A004C

Comment: For whatever reason I removed that line and added it back on and it seems to be working. Somehow I must have messed something up the first time.